# Which Regular Expression Algorithm does Javascript use for Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm, language-agnostic, unix

I was reading [this article](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) today on two different regular expression algorithms.

According to [the article](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) old Unix tools like ed, sed, grep, egrep, awk, and lex, all use what's called the Thompson NFA algorithm in their regular expresssions...

However newer tools like Java, Perl, PHP, and Python all use a different algorithm for their regular expressions that are much, much slower.

[This article](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) makes no mention at all of Javascript's regex algorthim,  (and yes I know there are various JS engines out there) but I was wondering if anybody knew which of those algorithms they use, and if maybe those algorithms should be swapped out for Thompson NFA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Javascript ECMA language description doesn't impose a requirement for the particular implementation of regular expressions, so that part of the question isn't well-formed.  You're really wondering about the particular implementation in a particular browser.

The reason Perl/Python etc use a slower algorithm, though, is that the regex language defined isn't *really* regular expressions.  A real regular expression can be expressed as a finite state machine, but the language of regex is context free.  That's why the fashion is to just call it "regex" instead of talking about regular expressions.

#### Update

Yes, in fact javascript regex isn't <s>content free</s> regular. Consider the syntax using `{n,m}', that is, matches from *n* to *m* accepted regexs.   Let *d* the difference *d*=|*n-m*|.  The syntax means there exists a string *ux<sup>d</sup>w* that is acceptable, but a string *ux<sup>k>d</sup>w* that is not.  It follows via the pumping lemma for regular languages that this is not a regular language.

(augh.  Thinko corrected.)

Comment: So the regular expressions in Javascript aren't full regular expressions...yeah, I think remember something about that when I was trying to do a lookbehind in Javascript and stumbled across an article on it faking it instead: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Comment: Actually, they're *more* than full regular expressions.  "{n,m}", for example, can't be represented in an FSA for arbitrary n,m.

Comment: The spec DOES dictate certain capabilities, like backreferences and lookaheads, which aren't possible in a DFA's or Thompson NFA's, so it's valid to say that JavaScript regexes are Traditional NFA's.

Comment: @AlanM Only if a "traditional NFA" isn't actually an NFA.  The proof's up there: a javascript regex defines a language that isn't regular.

Comment: Of course. If regexes were limited to matching regular languages, they would be an obscure academic topic and not a feature of scores of programming languages, tools and applications.

Comment: @lee eh, just another grad school flashback.  @AlanM actually, that's mistaken too.  sed, grep, egrep vi, etc -- all the things that are handled by the "traditional" Thompson algorithm  -- *are* regular.

Comment: Your "update" about {n,m} is wrong.  x{3,5} can be written as xxx|xxxx|xxxxx which is perfectly regular and handled perfectly well with a DFA engine.

Comment: Many XML Schema validators transform {n,m} into NFA; there are also other efficient transformations - see http://xtech06.usefulinc.com/schedule/detail/118 . It's the back-refs which are the killer.

Comment: @Charlie, I may sound a little nieve on this one, but what makes an expression regular?

Comment: @Pete Whenever I tried to do that back refs (look behind) with the article that I mentioned, all they did was reverse the string, and run a look ahead, and then un-reverse the string...I guess it depends on the size of the string, but I can't see how that would take up so much time.

Comment: @Pete, read the first graf: "XML content models are a form of extended context-free grammar, ..." Context free is not finite.

Comment: @Jan, that's incorrect.  While any bounded example if finite, eg, {3,5}.  there's no upper bound in the grammar.  You tell me the number of states in your machine, I'll construct two languages that it can't distinguish

Comment: @lee, that's a bigger than I can do in a comment.  Have a look at the wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language  Basically, a regular language is one that can be recognized by a finite state machine.

Comment: The unbounded x{3,} can be rewritten as xxxx* which is regular and can be implemented with a DFA with 4 states. Try it at http://osteele.com/tools/reanimator/

Comment: And if you say that x{7,1238103284} might be a problem, it's not.  The state matchine will simply be a bit larger: 1238103285 states.

Comment: @ Charlie and Jan: I think Jan is correct here. a{3,5} implies aaa|aaaa|aaaaa which is a valid DFA, thus qualifying to be a regular language. Correct use of the pumping lemma is in the process of being verified.

Comment: @ Charlie: Say that you have x{3,5}. If you set the maximum pumping length to be 6 = 5+1 then, for all matching strings in the language L, they will not need to be confined to the lemmas due to the fact that they are all under the pumping length.

Comment: Guys, look.  @Jan aaaa* is a regular language, as is any string constructed with catenation and Kleene star.  Therefore it can be recognized by a DFA. @unk, maybe the issue is that any fixed n,m is finite strings, but arbitrary n,m aren't.

Comment: @Charlie, but when you define n and m for your language, it must be finite. And once you use a Kleene star, then it will always be possible to split the a's such that the middle portion can be repeated due to Kleene repetition.

Comment: I think that the demonstration is bogus. Since n and m are fixed when the regex is defined, you always can find an integer p > 0 (that only depends on the regex) such that every string w of length at least p and that matches the regex, can be written as w = xyz, |y| > 0, |xy| ≤ p, for all i ≥ 0, xy{i}z matches the regex. In my view, it's the `x(?=y)` syntax that is not regular.

Comment: Oops, I should really read the other comments before posting, I'm not the first person to report the mistake. But then, why is it still there? I'll update the answer when I'll get the time to build a valid proof.

Comment: @boumbh, you're not going to be able to.  See, here's the point: we're talking about a *language*, ie, the (infinite) set of strings generated by a particular grammar.  For any *particular* *n* and *m* with *n,m* ≥ 0, like, say, {3,5}, you can build an FSM to recognize it.  But the language of *all* strings described by *any* *n,m* ≥ 0 is not.  For an example, think about the set of all matching parentheses that is no more than 5 parens deep: that's a regular expression, because a simple FSM will recognize it. But the set of arbitrary matching parens is not. Proof by pumping lemma.

Comment: @Charlie You cannot define the "set of arbitrary matching parens" using a Javascript regex. A regular expression describes a regular language. I think you are confusing and trying and applying the pumping lemma on the regex language itself (that describes the set of regular expressions and can be used to build the set of regular languages by surjection). The regex language ( = a language that is used to describe regular languages) is not regular for the reasons you said.

Comment: @boumbh No, I'm talking about the set of strings defined by something with {n,m} for arbitrary *n,m* ≥ 0 in the "regular" expression, and I've exhibited a proof that shows why that set is not regular. Now, if you don't believe it, you might convince yourself in a couple ways: (1) we know that by definition the set of regular strings is the set containing the alphabet, and strings formed by combining the alphabet using catenation or Kleene star. Construct an expression using only those operators that will regconize any string in the set a{n,m} where a is an element of the alphbet.

Comment: @boumbh Alternately, consider a finite state machine (since FSMs recognize exactly the set of regular languages) that can recognize a string in that same set.  Exhibit on that works for all strings in the set, not just for some definite value of *n,m*.  You can't without adding a counter -- but adding a counter makes your machine equivalent to a pushdown automaton, and the recognized language is not regular.

Comment: I know this is kinda hard, I remember being confused by the same thing in grad school, when we had to simulate our FSAs with rocks and shells.

Comment: *“While any bounded example if finite, eg, {3,5}. there's no upper bound in the grammar. You tell me the number of states in your machine, I'll construct two languages that it can't distinguish”* The number of states depends on the number of repetitions. Yes, for any DFA with *k* states, there is a language it can’t recognize, but that doesn’t mean no DFA can recognize that language. Every integer is finite; that doesn’t mean there’s a finite number of them. Sorry if that’s a bit lacking, but I really don’t understand your point.

Comment: Let's use a different approach, a regular language, by definition, is recognizable by a regular expression. What is a regular expression, this definition is relying at?  You can find the formal definition here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition . It says, that you can use the union operation, '|'. Can you trace back a{2,5} or a{2,} to a more lengthy, union operation? Of course, because it is just a abbreviation! Means a{2,5} = {'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaaa'} = 'a|aa|aaa|aaaa|aaaaa', so the {n,m} is recognizable by regular languages!

Comment: Edit.: a{2,5} = {'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaaa'} = 'aa|aaa|aaaa|aaaaa'

Comment: You’re correct that JavaScript regular expressions aren’t regular, but the `{n,m}` syntax isn’t the reason for nor proof of that. The problem is that you’re misusing the pumping lemma. Consider the regular language {a}. It only matches `a`. It follows from the same misuse in your answer that it’s not a regular language. The key is that strings uxⁿw *in the language* having `n` *at least some finite number* (the pumping length) can be pumped in a regular language – *not* just any string.

Comment: (@Unknown already mentioned this, but you seemed to have misinterpreted the comment.)

Comment: this should not be the accepted answer, regex comes in different flavors, javascript uses traditional NFA, which is not POSIX NFA, hence its not upto the standard, BUT its regular expression and its not context free!

Comment: Did you notice the strikeout of "context free"?

Comment: @Bamieh: JavaScript regex aren’t regular – they support backreferences. `(a+)b\1` can’t be represented by an NFA.

Comment: @Bamieh I read the article he linked and according to it "Most of the time, in fact, regular expression matching in Perl is fast enough. As the graph shows, though, it is possible to write so-called “pathological” regular expressions that Perl matches very very slowly. In contrast, there are no regular expressions that are pathological for the Thompson NFA implementation." If this part is true, then Javascript has Perl like engine, because it is ReDoS vulnerable `/(a+)+x/.exec("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab")` will be solved in a few years with it. The reason is backtracking not backreference.

Answer (score 10):

Though the ECMA standard does not specify the algorithm an ECMAScript implementation should use, the fact that the standard mandates that ECMAScript regular expressions must support backreferences (\1, \2, etc.) rules out the DFA and "Thompson NFA" implementations.

Comment: Backreferences rule out DFA (deterministic finite automaton), but there are other ways to solve the problem (e.g. recursive backtracking). Perl uses memoized backtracking recursion which removes a lot of the downsides to recursive backtracking (still eats a lot of memory on certain patterns though).

Comment: Also, one easy optimization would be just to check first if the regexp was a 'real' regular expression first and only use the slower algorithm if not.  This is pretty obvious but I'm hoping to get a response as to whether the browser implementations actually do something like this.

Answer (score 3):

Perl uses a memoized recursive backtracking search and, as of some improvements in 5.10, no longer blows up on `perl -e '("a" x 100000) =~ /^(ab?)*$/;'`.  In recent tests I performed on an OS X box, Perl 5.10 outperformed `awk`, even in the cases where `awk`'s algorithm was supposed to be better.