# Which regular expression algorithm does PHP use?

Tags: php, regex, algorithm, pcre

After reading [this article](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) about two different types of regular expression algorithms (Perl 5.8.7 and Thompson NFA), the latter being ~1,000,000 times faster than the former, according to the article. I use PHP daily, and use regex quite a lot, so I wanted to know which algorithm PHP uses.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727565/which-regular-expression-algorithm-does-javascript-use-for-regex), however it's only for JavaScript. One of the answers states that JavaScript uses the Thompson NFA algorithm, but that will of course vary from implementation to implementation. I think PHP may have switched to using the faster algorithms when it moved to it's `PCRE` set of functions, deprecating the `ereg_*` stuff.

I've looked at the [PHP PCRE documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) and, as far as I could see, it tells me nothing as to what algorithm it uses. The acronym `PCRE`, to me, tells me that it uses `Perl Compatible Regular Expressions`, so I assume it uses the Perl style algorithm.

Which regular expression algorithm does PHP use? Is it "Perl 5.8.7 style", or does it use the much faster Thompson NFA algorithm, or another one entirely? Could it even use a Perl backend to run it's expressions?

If PHP *does* use a Perl style algorithm, what exactly is it? I'm looking for an abstract definition/explanation in relation to other algorithms.

Comment: You're right, PCRE does stand for Perl-compatible regular expressions. However, that's not an algorithm.

Comment: PCRE typically means the [pcre library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcre), though, which uses the back-substituting Perl-style algorithms. IIRC the NFA approach only sees big performance gains for typical types of queries on huge datasets, though; 1,000,000 times is a dramatic overstatement for typical applications.

Comment: Note that the author of that article implemented a library called [`re2`](http://code.google.com/p/re2/), which uses traditional regular expressions and so is faster on certain inputs, especially large ones.  [`php-re2`](https://github.com/arraypad/php-re2) is a set of PHP bindings to `re2`; I have no idea if it's any good.

Comment: As an aside it would also be interesting to know what algorith MySql uses.

Comment: @Dougal Thank you for the link. From what I've read in the README, it looks very promising, and clean to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the manual:

http://www.php.net/pcre:

> Regular Expressions (**Perl-Compatible**)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php:

> The PCRE library is a set of functions that implement regular
>   expression pattern matching using the same syntax and semantics as
>   Perl 5, with just a few differences (see below). The current
>   implementation corresponds to Perl 5.005.