# How is regular expression matching implemented in Node / V8?

Tags: regex, node.js, performance, v8

I've come across [an article](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) that shows that regular expression matching is commonly implemented using a potentially under-performing algorithm vs. the suggested Thompson NFA algorithm.

With that in mind, how is this implemented in Node or V8? Is it possible to improve performance using a JS implementation of Thompson NFA, perhaps if only a limited subset of the features is used (perhaps removal of lookahead or other "advanced" features)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Regular Expression Algorithm does Javascript use for Regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727565/which-regular-expression-algorithm-does-javascript-use-for-regex)

Comment: @ndn - not quite, although related... that question isn't about the implementation details of NodeJS, it's about JavaScript, and it doesn't even make much sense to me since JavaScript is not an implementation, it's a language

Comment: @Amit JavaScript is most of the times criticized for not having lookbehinds so removing lookaround altogether doesn't seem viable.

Comment: @HamZa - perhaps this wasn't clear enough... what I meant was that if I had a certain requirement that didn't need lookaround, is it possible that a JS implementation will outperform the native implementation? (In other words, not looking to replace `RegExp` altogether, just have an "optimized" implementation for a subset of the cases)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in this [announcement](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/02/irregexp-google-chromes-new-regexp.html) from Chrome's development team, V8 engine uses [Irregexp](https://github.com/ashinn/irregex) regular expression engine:

Here are some quotes on the implementation of this engine:

> A fundamental decision we made early in the design of Irregexp was
>   that we would be willing to spend extra time compiling a regular
>   expression if that would make running it faster. During compilation
>   Irregexp first converts a regexp into an intermediate automaton
>   representation. This is in many ways the "natural" and most accessible
>   representation and makes it much easier to analyze and optimize the
>   regexp. For instance, when compiling /Sun|Mon/ the automaton
>   representation lets us recognize that both alternatives have an 'n' as
>   their third character. We can quickly scan the input until we find an
>   'n' and then start to match the regexp two characters earlier.
>   Irregexp looks up to four characters ahead and matches up to four
>   characters at a time.

> After optimization we generate native machine code which uses
>   backtracking to try different alternatives. Backtracking can be
>   time-consuming so we use optimizations to avoid as much of it as we
>   can. There are techniques to avoid backtracking altogether but the
>   nature of regexps in JavaScript makes it difficult to apply them in
>   our case, though it is something we may implement in the future.

So V8 does compile to a native automaton representation - though it does not use Thompson NFA.

As to performance, [this article](http://lh3lh3.users.sourceforge.net/reb.shtml) compares V8 regexp performance with other libraries/languages.